# Error "x and xtest must have the same number of columns" when using randomForest

Tags: r

I am getting an error when I am trying to use randomForest in R. 
When I enter

```
basic3prox  <- randomForest(activity ~.,data=train,proximity=TRUE,xtest=valid)
```

where train is a dataframe of training data and valid is a dataframe of test data,
I get the following error

```
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  x and xtest must have same number of columns
```

But they do have the same number of columns. I used subset() to get them from the same original dataset and when I run dim() i get

> dim(train)

[1] 3237  563

> dim(valid)

[1] 2630  563

So I am at a loss to figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: Generally, if you're passing in an argument for `xtest`, you wouldn't be using the formula method, you'd specify x and y separately.

Comment: Well whaddya know. It (sort of) is a bug. Passing `xtest` or `ytest` are supposed to generate a specific error when using a formula, but they don't appear to. I would contact the package maintainer.

Comment: That's strange because people have used the formula method in asking other questions about randomForest and not gotten an error (presumably) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696235/predict-function-in-randomforest-package-gives-different-results-from-randomfore

Comment: I agree that this is strange, pretty much all around. The bug itself seems like a strange one to me. The issue is the line `m <- match.call(expand = FALSE)` in `randomForest.formula`. It's possible that should be `expand = TRUE`.

Comment: Are there a lot of missing values?

Comment: The correct statement is randomForest(activity~.,data=train,proximity=TRUE, 
full answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321644/error-x-and-xtest-must-have-the-same-number-of-columns-when-using-randomforest
  xtest=valid[,names(valid)!='activity'],ytest=valid[,'activity'])

Comment: That may technically work, but you're still not supposed to use `xtest` with the formula interface. The fact that you can is probably a bug.

Comment: Since the formula should simply refer back to the dataframe,I am not understanding why it shouldn't be used. In this format, it's more like the predict.randomForest() in which you hand it something and point to a new dataset and let it run.

Comment: There's no philosophical reason why you can't do this, I'm just referring to the actual code, in which the author _clearly attempted_ to prevent you from doing this and simply messed it up. So it's more like I'm warning you not to count on this behavior in the future.

Answer (score 4):

No they don't; `train` has 562 predictor columns and 1 decision column, so `valid` must have 562 columns (and corresponding decision must be passed to `ytest` argument).
So the invocation should look like:

```
randomForest(activity~.,data=train,proximity=TRUE,
  xtest=valid[,names(valid)!='activity'],ytest=valid[,'activity'])
```

However, this is a dirty hack which will fail for more complex formulae and thus it shouldn't be used (even the authors tried to prohibit it, as Joran pointed out in comments). The correct, easier and faster way is to use separate objects for predictors and decisions instead of formulae, like this:

```
randomForest(trainPredictors,trainActivity,proximity=TRUE,
  xtest=testPredictors,ytest=testActivity)
```

Comment: So how do you explain the lines `if (any(c("xtest", "ytest") %in% names(m))) 
        stop("xtest/ytest not supported through the formula interface")` in `randomForest:::randomForest.formula`?

Comment: @joran Well, this if never fires because `x`/`ytest` are being bind to `...`; and the rest of the code simply deciphers the formula and jumps to the default method which handles `x`/`ytest` just fine. So, its a bug (;

Comment: I just can't tell which way the bug goes: did the author intend to prevent the use of `xtest` with the formula interface and mess it up, or was that once the case, and they intended to begin allowing it and they failed to remove that check from the function? ;)

Comment: Certainly the first option -- this works well only with `y~.` formulae, more complex ones may mess the order of attributes and thus produce completely wrong test predictions without any warning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not a bug. When you use `dim()`, you got different number. It means that training data and valid data do have different dims. I have encountered such problem. My solution is as following: First, I use `names()` show the variables in the training data and in valid data. I see they do have different variables; Second, I use `setdiff()` to "subtract" the surplus variables (if the training data has more variables than the valid data, then subtract the surplus variables in training data,vice versa.) After that, training data and valid data have the same variables. You can use **randomForest**.